# SwiftUI: Best way to include optional components in a SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui, components, viewmodel

We have a custom textfield defined in SwiftUI. This is the basic code for it:

```
 var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: Constants.cornerRadius, style: .continuous)
                .stroke(isFocused ? Color.blue : hasWarning ? .red : .gray, lineWidth: Constants.lineWidth)
            
            HStack {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.body)
                    .foregroundColor(isFocused ? Color.blue : hasWarning ? .red : .gray)
                    .padding(.horizontal, text.isEmpty ? Constants.Padding.horizontalIsEmpty : Constants.Padding.horizontalIsNotEmpty)
                    .background(text.isEmpty ? Color.clear : background)
                    .padding(.leading, Constants.Padding.leading)
                    .offset(y: text.isEmpty ? Constants.Offset.isEmpty : -(frameHeight / Constants.Offset.isNotEmptyRatio))
                    .scaleEffect(text.isEmpty ? Constants.ScaleEffect.isEmpty : Constants.ScaleEffect.isNotEmpty, anchor: .leading)
            }
            
            HStack {
                TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: { inFocus in
                    self.isFocused = inFocus
                })
                    .font(.body)
                    .padding(.horizontal, Constants.Padding.horizontal)
            }
        }
        .frame(height: frameHeight)
        .background(background)
        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: Constants.Animation.easeInOut))
        .padding(.top, Constants.Padding.top)
    }
```

Currently there's no viewModel linked to this. Now we want to extend this component to be able to include one (or both of):

- An internal button
- An icon in the textfield itself

I want to avoid adding any logic into the view and so I initially created a viewModel that looks something like this:

```
struct InternalTextfieldButtonProperties {
    let action: () -> Void
    let labelText: String
}

class TextFieldFloatingWithBorderViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let internalButtonProperties: InternalTextfieldButtonProperties?
    let icon: Image?
    
    var hasButton: Bool {
        return internalButtonProperties != nil
    }
    
    var hasIcon: Bool {
        return icon != nil
    }
    
    init(internalButtonProperties: InternalTextfieldButtonProperties? = nil, icon: Image? = nil) {
        self.internalButtonProperties = internalButtonProperties
        self.icon = icon
    }
}
```

The idea being that you can initialise this and then use the viewModel properties within the view to display the a button and or icon. However, this all seems a bit counterproductive as the icon and button properties in the viewModel would still need to be optional, which means again unwrapping in the view, taking away some of the point of having the viewModel. Indeed, if no icon or button is required, you end up declaring a viewModel for no reason.

I wondered if there's a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: To clarify: You want a reusable flexible TextField View that can optionally show an Icon and/or a button ? You might not need a view model for that ....

Comment: That’s right yes

Comment: One reason I'm keen to move this into a view model is for testing purposes